# The fastest Java algorithm for calculating nth term of Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: java, fibonacci

Is it known what is the fastest Java algorithm for calculating nth term of Fibonacci sequence ?

I have found [these algorithms](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Java) . I guess that Iterative algorithms should be faster than Recursive and Analytic algorithms .

Comment: You could test it! (you will just know for your own computer architecture though)

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not a discussion board. An appropriate question would be "I've tried profiling these algorithms and don't understand why I get this result".

Comment: @talnicolas These algorithms are just examples...I am asking if someone know which algorithm is known as fastest ...

Comment: Comment still applies.  That type of question belongs on [cstheory.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precalculate all Fibonacci numbers up to a sufficiently large number of n, and generate a source code snippet defining an array with the numbers in a type which can hold these numbers.

Then you can just retrieve the value in index `n` in your array.  This is `O(1)`.  Doesn't come much faster than that.

Comment: http://en.literateprograms.org/Fibonacci_numbers_(Java).  If you don't want to pre-calculate.  But of course pre-calculation is going to me MUCH faster.  On my I-7, the BigInteger series takes 60 seconds every thousand numbers once you reach 45,000, as long as you don't let it run out of memory.    I also pre-allocated the ArrayList to 200000, but it will be a while before it runs that long.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Programming#Fibonacci_sequence).  Create an array that holds every value of the n-1th Fibonacci number.  The first time it runs, it'll take about as long as a normal Fibonacci function, but subsequent calls can be run in O(1), since you'd already have the value in the array.

Comment: Probably.  I've removed that part of my answer though; the fact of the matter is that it will run on the same order of a normal Fibonacci function, but for Fib values <= N it will run on O(1).

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the analytic version is usually very fast in practice, but as Rosetta code notes, it's only accurate up to the 92nd number in the sequence.

The recursive version takes exponential time to run, so it's bound to be very slow even for moderately-sized *n*. The iterative and tail-recursive functions take time linear in *n*. A faster, O(lg *n*) time algorithm can be derived from the [matrix form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form) of the Fibonacci sequence.

See SICP for an explanation of the recursive and tail-recursive algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, as usual, "it depends". Generally you can't really store that many Fibonacci numbers since they tend to increase rather rapidly -- in fact, exponentially as exposed by the Analytic sections of your link.

So, for most practical purposes the answer is "don't compute -- cache." That is, use a lookup table. (Typically you'll need less than 100 entries before an overflow, anyways.)

For conventional storage methods, you're not going to do much better than just recursively computing it, as it's O(d^2) where d is the number of digits of output -- something that more complex arbitrary-sized number operations will have a hard time competing with.

"Analytic" is likely one of the slower methods since the bases are inconvenient and you'll be throwing away fast integer math.

Answer (score 2):

While you did target this at Java in particular, I was looking at different implementations of this in Python 3 last night. In particular, I looked at the naive recursive implementation and the analytic one (I called it the closed form one however). Here is the code, sans my unit test for it:

```
import math
from timeit import Timer

def fib_recursive(n):
    """
        Compute the Fibonacci sequence from a given number n
    """
    if n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        return fib_recursive(n - 2) + fib_recursive(n - 1)

def fib_closed_form(n):
    """
        Compute the Fibonacci sequence using a closed form.
    """
    def calc_golden_ratio():
        return (1 + math.sqrt(5)) / 2

    gr = calc_golden_ratio()
    inverse_gr = 1 - gr
    numerator = math.pow(gr,  n) - math.pow(inverse_gr,  n)
    return numerator // math.sqrt(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for n in range(0,  10):
        n = str(n)
        time = Timer("fib_closed_form(" + n + ")",  "from __main__ import fib_closed_form")
        print('Fib_Closed_Form(' + n +') = ' + str(time.timeit()))
        time = Timer("fib_recursive(" + n + ")",  "from __main__ import fib_recursive")
        print('Fib_Recursive(' + n +') = ' + str(time.timeit()))
```

Here are the timings for those functions with values from 1-10 (time is in seconds, measured using the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module). Each call is made by the timeit module 1000000 times by default, so it is the result of how long all the calls in total takes:

```
Python 3.2.2 (default, Nov 21 2011, 16:50:59) 
[GCC 4.6.2] on staggerlee, Standard
>>> 
Fib_Closed_Form(1) = 5.808775901794434
Fib_Recursive(1) = 0.6938691139221191

Fib_Closed_Form(2) = 6.142783880233765
Fib_Recursive(2) = 1.9276459217071533

Fib_Closed_Form(3) = 6.62189793586731
Fib_Recursive(3) = 3.6403379440307617

Fib_Closed_Form(4) = 6.376585960388184
Fib_Recursive(4) = 6.733421802520752

Fib_Closed_Form(5) = 6.566863059997559
Fib_Recursive(5) = 11.409136056900024

Fib_Closed_Form(6) = 6.521269083023071
Fib_Recursive(6) = 18.514809131622314

...

Fib_Closed_Form(10) = 6.631903886795044
Fib_Recursive(10) = 131.51839208602905
```

As you can see, the closed form of this has a higher up-front cost. The recursive one blows it out of the water! It only stays competitive up through a value of n = 4 though. You can see it's timing becoming worse and worse though. By the time we get up to around n = 6, we can already see this is not the right direction.

By the way, I attempted an n = 25 last night. The closed form took about the same amount of time, and the recursive form did not finish before I went to bed (at least half an hour of running).

My point is that these are fairly easy to implement, as well as straightforward to come up with some unit tests for. You can give it a shot and see the results for yourself in Java, though timing things in a language such as Java can be complex without additional setup.

Comment: How does timing change if you precalculate inverse_gr?

Comment: Good question. I have not timed that, but I'd guess just slightly better because of not having to use that nested function/make those calls to sqrt. Again though, just slightly, and it would only remove the constant factor down. The big picture is that it keeps consistent performance with scale.